# How to properly replace inline images with styled floating divs via PHP's DOMDocument?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm stuck on the following problem and would like to know if you got an advise.

A WYSIWYG editor allows the user to upload and embed images. However, my users are mostly scientists but don't have any knowledge of how to use HTML or even how to re-size images properly for a web page. That's why I am re-sizing the images automatically server-side to a thumbnail and a full view size. Clicking on a thumbnail shall open a lightbox with full image.

The WYSIWYG editor throws images into `<p>` tags just like this (see last paragraph):

```
<p>Intro Text</p>
<ul>
   <li>List point 1</li>
   <li>List point 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Some text before an image. 
   <img alt="Slide 1" src="/files/slide1.png" /> 
   Maybe some text in between, nobody knows what the scientists are up to. 
   <img alt="Slide 2" src="/files/slide2.png" /> 
   And even more text right after that.
</p>
```

What I would like to do is get the images out of the `<p>` Tags and add them before the respective paragraph within floating `<div>`s:

```
<p>Intro Text</p>
<ul>
   <li>List point 1</li>
   <li>List point 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="custom">
   <a href="/files/fullview/slide1.png" rel="lightbox[group][Slide 1]">
      <img src="/files/thumbs/files/slide1.png" />
   </a>
</div>
<div class="custom">
   <a href="/files/fullview/slide2.png" rel="lightbox[group][Slide 2]">
      <img src="/files/thumbs/files/slide2.png" />
   </a>
</div>
<p>Some text before an image. 
   Maybe some text in between, nobody knows what the scientists are up to. 
   And even more text right after that.
</p>
```

So what I need to do is to get all the image nodes of the html produced by the editor, process them, insert the divs and remove the image nodes.
After reading quite a lot of similar questions I'm missing something and can't get it to work. Probably, I am still misunderstanding the whole concept behind DOM manipulation.
Here's what I came up with til now:

```
// create DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// load WYSIWYG html into DOMDocument
$doc->loadHTML($html_from_editor);
// create DOMXpath
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// create list of all first level DOMNodes (these are p's or ul's in most cases)
$children = $xpath->query("/");
foreach ( $children AS $child ) {
    // now get all images
    $cpath = new DOMXpath($child);
    $images = $cpath->query('//img');
    foreach ( $images AS $img ) {
        // get attributes
        $atts = $img->attributes;
        // create replacement
        $lb_div = $doc->createElement('div');
        $lb_a = $doc->createElement('a');
        $lb_img = $doc->createElement('img');
        $lb_img->setAttribute("src", '/files/thumbs'.$atts->src);
        $lb_a->setAttribute("href", '/files/fullview'.$atts->src);
        $lb_a->setAttribute("rel", "lightbox[slide][".$atts->alt."]");
        $lb_a->appendChild($lb_img);
        $lb_div->setAttribute("class", "custom");
        $lb_div->appendChild($lb_a);
        $child->insertBefore($lb_div);
        // remove original node
        $child->removeChild($img);
    }
}
```

Problems I ran into:

1. `$atts` is not populated with values. It does contain the right attribute names, but values are missing.
2. `insertBefore` should be called on the child's parent node if I understood that right. So, it should rather be `$child->parentNode->insertBefore($lb_div, $child);` but the parent node is not defined.
3. Removal of original img tag does not work.

I'd be thankful for any advise what I am missing. Am I on the right track or should this be done completely different?

Thans in advance,
Paul

Comment: does the WYSIWYG editor create valid XHTML?

Comment: The editor does not add <html> or <body> tags but the content itself is actually valid (the editor in use is CKEditor).

Comment: @Paul: Your code is full of errors that hinder you to solve your problem (and to improve it). If you enable error reporting and display the errors it can help you: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Gordon & hakre: Thanks for both of your answers. As I stated I'm kind of new to DOMDocument and will look into both your solutions. I indeed got quite some errors, mostly stating I was using methods on non-objects. I'll see what I can learn from your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, your code had multiple errors which prevented you from getting started. Your concept looks quite well from what I see and the code itself only had minor issues.

1. You were iterating over the document root element. That's just one element, so picking up all images therein.
2. The second xpath must be relative to the child, so starting with `.`.
3. If you load in a HTML chunk, DomDocument will create the missing elements like `body` around it. So you need to address that for your xpath queries and the output.
4. The way you accessed the attributes was wrong. With error reporting on, this would have given you error information about that.

Just take a look through the working code I was able to assemble ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WgcEUU)). I've left some notes:

```
$html_from_editor = <<<EOD
<p>Intro Text</p>
<ul>
   <li>List point 1</li>
   <li>List point 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Some text before an image. 
   <img alt="Slide 1" src="/files/slide1.png" /> 
   Maybe some text in between, nobody knows what the scientists are up to. 
   <img alt="Slide 2" src="/files/slide2.png" /> 
   And even more text right after that.
</p>
EOD;

// create DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// load WYSIWYG html into DOMDocument
$doc->loadHTML($html_from_editor);
// create DOMXpath
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

// create list of all first level DOMNodes (these are p's or ul's in most cases)
# NOTE: this is XHTML now
$children = $xpath->query("/html/body/p");

foreach ( $children AS $child ) {
    // now get all images
    $cpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $images = $cpath->query('.//img', $child); # NOTE relative to $child, mind the .

    // if no images are found, continue
    if (!$images->length) continue;

    // insert replacement node
    $lb_div = $doc->createElement('div');
    $lb_div->setAttribute("class", "custom");
    $lb_div = $child->parentNode->insertBefore($lb_div, $child);


    foreach ( $images AS $img ) {
        // get attributes
        $atts = $img->attributes;
        $atts = (object) iterator_to_array($atts); // make $atts more accessible    

        // create the new link with lighbox and full view
        $lb_a = $doc->createElement('a');
        $lb_a->setAttribute("href", '/files/fullview'.$atts->src->value);
        $lb_a->setAttribute("rel", "lightbox[slide][".$atts->alt->value."]");

        // create the new image tag for thumbnail
        $lb_img = $img->cloneNode(); # NOTE clone instead of creating new
        $lb_img->setAttribute("src", '/files/thumbs'.$atts->src->value);

        // bring the new nodes together and insert them
        $lb_a->appendChild($lb_img);
        $lb_div->appendChild($lb_a);

        // remove the original image
        $child->removeChild($img);
    }
}

// get body content (original content)
$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->query("/html/body/*") as $child) {
    $result .= $doc->saveXML($child); # NOTE or saveHtml 
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: I ended up using code very similar to your contribution. Thanks a lot for making me aware of my errors. I did indeed read something about the automatic addition of html and body tags but didn't really cared about that in my first attempts. Your way of retrieving the original image attributes didn't work even though it looks right to me. var_export always returned NULL for the DOMNodeList as well as any attribute. So I used Gordons way of getting the attributes which works perfect for now. Taking both your solutions into account, yours did help me more in understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that attribute retrieving was a bit of playful way of doing things. Gordon's way is the one the API provides, and quite comfortable as well. I think Gordon solution is very valuable and as you got two longer answers I think this helps you to really get a big picture of this. It's not easy in the beginning to combine domDocument and xpath if both is new, I know that for myself. But those are really valuable tools and they work really well.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it ([demo](http://codepad.org/iHFSamzB)):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML("<div>$xhtml</div>"); // we need the div as root element

// find all img elements in paragraphs in the partial body
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('/div/p/img') as $img) {

    $parentNode = $img->parentNode; // store for later
    $parentNode->removeChild($img); // unlink all found img elements

    // create a element
    $a = $dom->createElement('a');
    $a->setAttribute('href', '/files/fullview/' . basename($img->getAttribute('src')));
    $a->setAttribute('rel', sprintf('lightbox[group][%s]', $img->getAttribute('alt')));
    $a->appendChild($img);

    // prepend img src with path to thumbs and remove alt attribute
    $img->setAttribute('href', '/files/thumbs' . $img->getAttribute('src'));
    $img->removeAttribute('alt'); // imo you should keep it for accessibility though

    // create the holding div
    $div = $dom->createElement('div');
    $div->setAttribute('class', 'custom');
    $div->appendChild($a);

    // insert the holding div
    $parentNode->parentNode->insertBefore($div, $parentNode);
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. As a whole I couldn't get it to work, the only output ever was the xml declaration line. I am not experienced enough to debug this but I did use your way to get the attributes from the original images.

Comment: @Paul im not sure what you mean by you couldnt get it to work as a whole. The code snippet above produces the wanted output you show in your question. Click the demo link on top to see.

Comment: I did look at the demo and the more I was confused why it didn't work when I embedded that into my code. The last two lines regarding the output still do puzzle me. But even when I changed that bit the script always returned <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?--> and nothing else.

Comment: @Paul formatOutput in combination with preserveWhiteSpace at the top makes sure you get a pretty printed xml string instead of a compact one. Passing the documentElement to saveXml makes sure you dont get the xml prolog.

Comment: Now that's weird since I got the xml prolog and only that. Well, then I probably messed something up.
But I really appreciate your solution, I got quite some understanding of the whole system out of it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul you're welcome. I've got a few more DOM related answers on StackOverflow in case you are interested in more code snippets: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom